# null pointer exception Pascal Triangle

Tags: java

Hello i got a little problem with my program here is a code

```
public class zad1
{
    static public class WTP
    {
        int[] wiersz;

        int silnia(int a)
        {
            if (a < 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return a * silnia(a - 1);
            }
        }

        WTP(int n)
        {
            int wiersz[] = new int[n+1];

            for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++)
            {
                wiersz[i] =  silnia(n) / ( silnia(n - i) * silnia(i) ); 
            }              
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        WTP tablica = new WTP(a1);

        for(int i = 1; i<=args.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tablica.wiersz[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And i getting an error after runing it:

> Exception in thread main java.lang.nullpointerexpception at
>   zad1.java:58.

The 58 line is : `System.out.println(tablica.wiersz[i]);`

The point of program is to create an line of pascal triangle put a values into it. After that when runing it on console with arguments for example java zad1 4 0 1 its should count values in 4 line of triangle and print the values of positions which is given after 4.

Any idea whats wrong? :/ 
Thanks for help its runing now but  there is one problem its counting posistion + 1 instead of posistion for example in 4 line the values should be for 0-1 , 1-4 , 2-6, 3-4 but its show 0-4 , 1-6, 2-4 i changed for(int i = 1; i<=args.length; i++) to i=0 but its didnt help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a local variable called `wiersz` inside the `WTP` constructor.

Change the line to `this.wiersz = new int[n+1];` in the `WTP` constructor.

Comment: I try that and getting 4 errors : with symbols [, ], ; , and last one saying that is not a statement all in line 35: wiersz[] = new int[n+1];

Comment: what are the errors and where are you getting them??

Comment: When i try to change to this.wiersz[] ... a get error when compile zad1.java:35 illegal start of expression and its pointing on [] symbol

Comment: Thanks you very much is working now but there is one problem its counting posistion + 1 instead of posistion for example in 4 line the values should be for 0-1 , 1-4 , 2-6, 3-4 but its show 0-4 , 1-6, 2-4